# Add html element in package component dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a new table row in thead on react-bootstrap-table-next

hear is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    var d1 = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0]
    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
        onChange={
          (e)=>{
            alert(e.target.id)
          }
        }
      />
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>')
  }, [])
```

in this code the JSX syntax of onChange not working so can you please suggest what is the best way to append a html in thead tag

Comment: You are inputting jsx into a browser dom method which expects html. You should probably put the jsx in its own component. Inserting html this way is kind of a react anti pattern can you share the code for the whole component

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shockley-vreip?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I cant get this sandbox to run. The deps seem strange. So are you trying to hack some behaviour into the bootstrap library? Thats why you are trying to do it this way?

Comment: yes I want new tr in thead that's why i want to append the html

Comment: @Jazz do you have any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Well to do what you want to do you need to change the way the onChange is called, change that to HTML and the onchange handler will work. https://codesandbox.io/s/green-flower-hp88h Ive made an example for you. However updating the dom like this MAY break the react virtual dom depending on the implementation of the bootstrap components

Comment: It is a good idea but how can I get the input value??

Comment: and also may be in this way i cannot able to change the state right?

Comment: You could set the function within the react component so you can access the state setter. And you can change the value in the input using vanilla JS too. But the problem is if react tries to render the part of your app where you have added elements then it wont match and the bahaviour will be wrong.

Comment: Any other way to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235004/discussion-between-jazz-and-mitesh-k).